# alternative to sql rank () over (partition by... order by..)

Tags: sql

I am trying assign a rank like the one in the example below (**rowFinal**), where the rows are partitioned by **GalleryId** and ordered by **StartDateKey** ascending. However, I need to have a 'New' **EventName** restart the count back from 1 like in the example below with StartdateKey 20131219.

```
GalleryId   StartDateKey    row EventName   rowFinal    
425934233   20130226         1    Renew        1    
425934233   20130326         2    Renew        2    
425934233   20130426         3    Renew        3    
425934233   20130526         4    Renew        4    
425934233   20130626         5    Renew        5     
425934233   20131219         6    New          1    
425934233   20140119         7    Renew        2    
425934233   20140219         8    Renew        3    
425934233   20140319         9    Renew        4    
425934233   20140419         10   Renew        5    
…                   
425931351   20121210         1    Renew        1    
425931351   20130110         2    Renew        2    
425931351   20130210         3    Renew        3    
425931351   20130310         4    Renew        4    
425931351   20130410         5    Renew        5    
425931351   20130510         6    Renew        6    
425931351   20130610         7    Renew        7    
425931351   20130710         8    Renew        8    
425931351   20130810         9    Renew        9
```

Parsing and updating each row (while loops) proved not practical due to speed. Any suggestions would be profoundly appreciated.

Comment: tag your database please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a trick.  The idea is to group rows based on the number of "New" records before it.  Then you can do this using a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by GalleryId, numRenew order by startdatekey) as rowFinal
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when EventName = 'Renew' then 1 else 0 end) over 
                 (partition by partition by GalleryId order by startdatekey) as numRenew
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Great idea!

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the different sections into different queries and unioning them together.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, 
row_number() over(partition by galleryid,substring(startdatekey,7,2) order by startdatekey)
as rowFinal
from tablename;
```

It looks like you are partitioning on galleryid and also on the last 2 characters of startdatekey.